# Overlapped part of tooltip of slider and his position in bootstrap-slider plugin

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2, bootstrap-slider

I use Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 and [bootstrap-slider](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider) plugin in modal window. The problem is that part of tooltip of slider is overlapped behind header of modal window and has wrong position.

[image]

I tried to add this rule, but it didn't help.

```
.slider .tooltip{
    z-index: 1151 !important;
}
```

I would like to provide correct jsfiddle, but I am not able to find bootstrap-slider plugin cdn. Here is jsfiddle, which doesn't work because bootstrap-slider plugin source is missing.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0sryor13/)

**html**

```
    <a href="#options" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<div id="options" class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3>Settings</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
      Vertex size <input id="nodeSize" data-slider-id='nodeSizeSlider' type="text" data-slider-min="1" data-slider-max="50" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="20"/><br><br>
      Edge size <input id="edgeSize" data-slider-id='edgeSizeSlider' type="text" data-slider-min="1" data-slider-max="50" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="20"/><br>
  </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="saveSettings">Save</button>
      </div>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
            $('#nodeSize').slider({
                    formatter: function(value) {
                            return value;
                    }
            });

            $('#edgeSize').slider({
                    formatter: function(value) {
                            return value;
                    }
            });
});
```

Comment: Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0sryor13/1/) with plugin

Comment: @TJ in your fiddle the tooltip is still overlapped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your Javascript:

```
$("body").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
    $("#edgeSize").slider('relayout');
    $("#nodeSize").slider('relayout');
});
```

**Explanation:** When modal is shown the function relayout is run on both input fields and renders the tooltip again after initialization.

**Source:** https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider#functions

**Updated JSfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/0sryor13/3/

Answer (score 2):

For z-index to work, the element you are applying it to must have position other than static, for example

```
.slider .tooltip{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1151 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but the tooltip is still overlapped behind header of modal window

Comment: Have you checked to see if the parent confusing the modal content has an overflow hidden that maybe obscuring the tooltip?

Comment: Here is your problem, the modal-body element has overflow-y: auto;
By removing that your tooltip will appear

Comment: @Zoheiry Thank you Zoheiry, the tooltip is visible now.